# Nested grid do not fire event

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Here is a nested grid with some event :

```
<%--BLOCK : TEST--%>
<telerik:GridTableView  CssClass="noColapse" runat="server" Name="RptPV" DataSourceID="LDS_PV_info" DataKeyNames="MSE_compteur" HierarchyDefaultExpanded="True" 
                        OnCallingDataMethods="Unnamed_CallingDataMethods" 
                        OnDataBinding="Unnamed_DataBinding" 
                        OnDisposed="Unnamed_Disposed" 
                        OnCreatingModelDataSource="Unnamed_CreatingModelDataSource" 
                        OnDataBound="Unnamed_DataBound" 
                        OnInit="Unnamed_Init" 
                        OnLoad="Unnamed_Load" 
                        OnPreRender="Unnamed_PreRender" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        OnUnload="Unnamed_Unload"   >
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Unnamed_CallingDataMethods(object sender, CallingDataMethodsEventArgs e)
    { this.here.Text += "CallingDataMethods";}

protected void Unnamed_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { this.here.Text += "Unnamed_DataBinding";}

protected void Unnamed_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { this.here.Text += "Unnamed_Disposed";}

protected void Unnamed_CreatingModelDataSource(object sender, CreatingModelDataSourceEventArgs e)
    { this.here.Text += "Unnamed_CreatingModelDataSource";}

protected void Unnamed_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { this.here.Text += "Unnamed_DataBound";}

(...)
```

And my *here.text* stay empty. But the nested grid is displayed.

I need to access a parent key value, collapse a nested grid, hide a nested grid or count the number of row. 
There will be no edit, no row click, those grid are only displaying data in *templated columns* > *Item Template* .

Is there a way for a nested grid to fire event? 
In witch on those even may I access databounded information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested grid DO NOT Fire event!

If you need to access detail tables , items etc . 
You need to add an  method to the `PreRender` in the `MasterTableView` like this:

```
<MasterTableView   DataSourceID="myDataSource"
                   AllowMultiColumnSorting="True" 
                   DataKeyNames="Key1,Key2,KeyN" 
                   HierarchyDefaultExpanded="True"
                   OnPreRender="Unnamed_PreRender" >
```

The method will iterate through the grid using recursively.
The way you do it can change depending on your `HieararchyLoadMode`.

So this is my way to do it, easiest way exist if you are on `Client` or `Serverbind` mode.

```
protected void Unnamed_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // MyControler is my recursive method.
    MyControler(RadGRID_MASTER.MasterTableView);
}



private void MyControler(GridTableView gridTableView)
{
    GridItem[] nestedViewItems = gridTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.NestedView);    
    foreach (GridNestedViewItem nestedViewItem in nestedViewItems)
    {
        foreach (GridTableView nestedView in nestedViewItem.NestedTableViews)
        {
            // Here you can operate your controls the way you want.
            if (nestedView.Name == "LAC" && nestedView.Items.Count == 0)
            {  
                // Do stuff 
            }

            if(nestedView.HasDetailTables)
            {
                MyControler(nestedView); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```